# How to Make Keypresses Using PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using PyAutoGUI to try to code a macro. For this macro, I need to press a key to select something. To interact with the screen, I am using PyAutoGUI. Any ideas on how to press the key?

I have tried using this command.

```py
pyautogui.press("s")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That code is correct. Is the window you want the S sent to you not in focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if anyone has helped out here or if you got this resolved in the end.

First, the documentation can be found here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#keyboard-functions#

When passing a keystroke, you want to use "typewrite" and not "press"

Press "S"

```
pyautogui.typewrite("s")
```

Press Hotkey (Ctrl + S)

```
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl" + "s")
```

Press key as a variable

```
pyautogui.keydown(variable)
```